Reference Request: Clustering s.t. $Mean\approx Median$ - Is this just $k$-means?
Suppose we are given a set  $D = \{x_i\}_{i\in [N]}\subset\mathbb R$ (finitely many data points on the real line). For any such set we can define its arithmetic mean as $mean(D)$ and its median as $median(D)$.
Consider now the following task:
For fixed $\epsilon >0$ find a coarsest partition $D=\dot{\bigcup}_{j=1}^K A_j$ s.t. for all $j\in [K]$ one has $\lvert mean(A_j) - median(A_j)\rvert <\epsilon$.
I am pretty sure that this has been considered before and I was wondering whether this is just something like $k$-means clustering in disguise.
Motivation Suppose you asked one hundred people for their age and it happened to be the case that half of them are above 90 years old and the other half is below ten years old. Depending on the task it might then be very useful to cluster this data into these two piles and go from there. From my intuition a method for the above task would precisely perform such a partition for a desired $\epsilon$.
Any reference is appreciated.

You are searching for a division of a data set $D$ on the real line so that in each of the subsets of the partition, the mean and the median are close (within $\epsilon$). This is not really k-means but it has a similar spirit.
The main difference is in the target. K-means is concerned with minimizing the variance (or within-cluster squared distances), which is known as the centroid. Here, the task is given to find those subsets where the relationship between mean and median is controlled:
$$|mean(A_j) - median(A_j)| < \epsilon$$
This is more than a matter of variance; it is about uncovering subsets with a special distributional symmetry. Analyzing it in such a manner as locating the clusters with the necessary data would be the job. The proximity of the mean and median in each cluster indicates a certain level of symmetry or the lack of skewness, or heavy tails. If the mean and median are significantly different, it suggests skewness or outliers, which would be grouped into separate clusters.
K-means wouldn't care about the relationship between mean and median but could provide a partition with some of the clusters that, by chance, will meet your condition. The algorithm you are speaking about is especially designed for this purpose.
One has also to deal with the "coarsest" part.
It should be noted that "the coarsest" may be misleading as it's possible that for some $\epsilon$, there are two or more completely different partitions that achieve the same result (as coarse as possible). For example, with 101 people, 50 age 10, 50 others age 90, and one age 50, and a small $\epsilon$, we can make a "young" and "old" partition with the 50-year-old dropped in either one, and achieve the goal. So, "coarsest" should probably be "as coarse as possible", meaning that we should seek to minimize the number of clusters while adhering to the given condition*. K-means is a typical case when you have to tell how many clusters k you want to be, while your approach has a k which originates from the data. Consequently, one needs to come up with a model that comprises automatic selection of the number of clusters.
One could also consider a greedy partitioning algorithm instead of k-means. Take one dataset, it is always possible to find a partition such that every single cluster is in conformity with the said condition, as the singleton partition always meets this condition. In the case when the set of the most maiden clusters has the smallest number of points in each cluster. However, there would also be a single cluster from the whole dataset. Thus, this could be the greedy division of the whole data. For instance, try to start with the whole dataset as a single cluster. Then, if $|mean(D) - median(D)| < \epsilon$ is met we may be through, if otherwise the opposite is true, we will try to divide it into two clusters, and verify that the clusters satisfy the condition. There may be multiple ways to split, for instance, by splitting at the median, or trying different options and keeping only the ones for which the new clusters satisfy the condition. Then, we can refine each of the clusters using this approach. This part of the process may need to be discussed in detail, perhaps a recursive method, but the basic idea is the division is refined till your condition is satisfied. The greedy algorithm can stumble across any of the valid partitions (as coarse as possible).
So when trying to partition a dataset, both k-means and your problem databases come across issues that deal with different metrics for the clusters. Your problem is concerned with the detection of clusters that point to the equivalent distributions feature, that identifies the mean that is very close to the median. It is rather an enhancement through utilizing the means and medians features. It is neither simply k-means presented in a roundabout fashion nor a similarly approaching type of problem, but nevertheless has some common spirit with the general clustering.

Note, too, that "the coarsest" may be misleading -- it's possible that for some $\epsilon$, there are two completely different partitions that achieve the same result. Example: 101 people, 50 age 10, 50 others age 90, one age 50. $\epsilon = 1$. Making a "young" and "old" partition, with the 50-year-old dropped in either one, achieves the goal. So "coarsest" should probably be "as coarse as possible".

@JohnHughes Thanks for correcting me, I have edited my answer if it still have any error just tell me.

Oh...I really should have made that comment about the question itself! I thought your answer was fine. :)
